# material stretching unity and tiles don't work and uv mapping not working because need Pro builder

Tags: unity-game-engine, material-design, textures, render-to-texture, uv-mapping

I want to put material on the wall and it stretches. Idk why
[as you can see this is the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6G1G.png)

I want to make the material not stretching if the wall is too big for the material, repeat a half or a quarter to fill it, if it was too small just make it apply half or quarter of the material not the whole texture.

I tried to search baidu google and stackoverflow and I found nothing usefull, even chatgpt don't.

Comment: so change the material to tile?

Comment: oh and if you want to install pro builder, install it, its free